# Facebook Comments plugin will not go width 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the link to my page:
http://whiterootmedia.com/database/test/mobile8.html

The comments plugin is a couple pixels to wide when minimized and when viewed on a mobile phone I think it goes to a width of 500px (I think).

Here's the css that I'm using now:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe {width: 100% !important;}
.fb-comments span {width: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: It is already 100%. It should be caching issue! Check out: http://i.imgur.com/uFrdH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It is already 100%. It should be caching issue!

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

#### Screenshot

[image]

---

You should not give both `border` / `margin` / `padding` with 100% `width`. Instead, use a wrapper `div`, with the `border`, and inside that, the `iframe` has 100%. The problem is solved. And don't give any `width` or `float` to the parent `div` with the `border`.

Comment: Look at the right border. How do i fix it where it lines up normally?

Comment: You want them small or big? I don't get you? Or you want them to be surrounded by the border?

Comment: Gotcha! Remove the `width` from `#comments`.

Comment: The comments box is 6pixels too wide (3pixels for the left border, 3 pixels for the right border). So actually I think I need a width of 100% - 6 pixels.

Comment: So do this. You should not give both `border` / `margin` / `padding` with 100% `width`. Instead, use a wrapper `div`, with the `border`, and inside that, the `iframe` has 100%. The problem is solved. And don't give any `width` or `float` to the parent `div` with the `border`.

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda new to stackoverflow, do I checkmark the "It is already 100%. It should be caching issue!" answer even though the real solution was a follow up reply below it?

Comment: @Dusty I added that in the answer. You can now click the checkmark.